# Is possible to increase or reduce the brightness of the clip when i do the 3D Tracking?

Tags: tracking

I'm using blender to track a lot of video clip end insert 3D objects on the scenes. Blender does a very good job but sometimes i have difficult to do this because some parts of the videos are too much dark or to mach clear. There is a way to increase or reduce the brightness inside of the window "movie clip editor"? (after effects style)

Answer (score 1):

one way you could achieve this is by changing the multiply value in "Color" on your strip:

[image]

or go to modifiers (click on tab on the right side):

[image]

add modifier bright/contrast:

[image]

then change bright value:

[image]